# Bootstrap Glyphicons not rendering using local Bootstrap version

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, glyphicons

I am using bootstrap in django and it works perfectly for all other bootstrap classes except icon classes like: `class="glyphicon glyphicon-download-alt"`

**Snapshot with error at right bottom:**

[image]

**Snapshot when bootstrap.min.css file included:**

[image]

> On doing inspect element it contain all glyphicons its snapshot is-

[image]

It only works if I link `http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css` in my html file; but it does'nt work if I include my `bootstrap.min.css` from my PC. Otherwise, every bootstrap class works perfectly. Hope you understand my problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean included from your PC? You are building locally? If so please also test the page in Chrome to see if the same error occurs as in Firefox. Actually it does not have to be Chrome, but at least a non Mozilla based browser.

Comment: No i have downloaded it from above link and saved in my PC  and it work perfect for all bootstrap classes

Comment: Did you also download the glyphicons font?

Comment: Not explicitly, I just open the link and copy all displaying content in my css file, and i think all fonts are included in it as in above image of inspect element. Thanks

Comment: No, they aren't. Please re-read my answer. The CSS that you copied only contains links to glyphicons, not the actual font itself.

Comment: Ok then how can i get the actual font.

Comment: Please re-read my answer. Visit the download link from the official site that I have linked to. There are instructions there for installing the full bootstrap package.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It isn't working because you saved the CSS file from the CDN link. That won't work, because the glyphicons are linked to relative to that CSS file. Example:

```
@font-face{
    font-family:'Glyphicons Halflings';
    src:url(../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot);
}
```

What this means, is that the downloaded Bootstrap file is looking for the glyphicons in a folder **on your computer** (which you don't have).

You need to properly download Bootstrap from [the official download link](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started#download). This official download contains a `/fonts/` directory that contains the actual glyphicon font files.

Alternatively, you could change all of the font paths in the CDN file to be absolute links to the fonts on the CDN...but that doesn't really make sense.

Comment: I have tried it but it still don't works. Its snapshot contain all Glyphicons file. Plz help.

Comment: If you download the official zip, it will work out of the box. The only way it won't is if you move something without changing the relative links.

Comment: Actually i am working in django and i just copy css file in my static folder and it work for other classes. Also tell me what is CDN. Thanks

Comment: You'd probably also need to copy the `fonts` folder to your static folder.

Comment: Thanks, was looking for solution to this problem quite some time!

Answer (score 0):

Finally my problem is resolved. Actually the problem was while using Glyphicons in our website like in django, we also have to copy font folder from bootstrap-3.3.2-dist folder downloaded from [bootstrap official link](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/)

Another problem is where to fix it. See this structure where fonts is respect to css file and then paste fonts folder.

```
bootstrap/
├── less/
├── js/
├── fonts/
├── dist/
│   ├── css/
│   ├── js/
│   └── fonts/
└── docs/
    └── examples/
```

But it worked for me in django just inside static folder.

Comment: I think that just switching your bootstrap.min.css with the one contained in the dist fixes the problem.