# How to use bootstrap without online link?

Tags: html, css

How to use bootstrap without these link "https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"

I have downloaded bootstrap.min.css file and I am using this class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" on localhost but this is not working and not displaying search icon on their site.

Comment: download the css and js in website , then call it locally

Comment: Read this: [CSS How To...](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp)

Comment: Follow this http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bootstrap Glyphicons not rendering using local Bootstrap version](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28645733/bootstrap-glyphicons-not-rendering-using-local-bootstrap-version) and several others

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because your browser is looking for the glyphicon in the folders on your computer.  If you are loading bootstrap from CDN, glyphicons are linked relative to the CSS file. Example below...

Download bootstrap from here: http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#download

Example from your external bootstrap file:

```
@font-face{font-family:'Glyphicons Halflings';src:url(../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot);
```

You can change font paths to absolute, download fonts and place in proper folder, or download proper bootstrap file (not CDN).

Answer (score -1):

first copy your bootstrap.min.css file in your project folder then Put this code in your head section of html file

```
<link href="bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Answer (score -2):

If your folder structure is something like this:

```
|-- index.html
|-- style
    |-- bootstrap.min.css
```

Then you'll want to call it in the  section of your index.html file. Like this:

```
<head>
  <!-- Other stuff will likely be in here... -->
  <link href="/style/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
```

If you have minimized javascript files, you'll want to put them at the end of the  section in a  tag like this:

```
<body>
    <!-- Other stuff will likely be in here... --> 
    <!-- Assume you have a directory named js at the same level as your HTML file -->
    <script src="js/main.min.js"></script>
</body>
```